# ruby: installing debugger

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can't get debugger installed to work in my ruby files. Can anyone see what the problem is?

I did 'require debugger' at the top of my file.rb and got this error when I ran `ruby file.rb`

```
rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- debugger (LoadError)
```

I did `gem install debugger` on my system but got this error message.

```
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-1.9.3-rc1 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
```

When I run gem environment, I get

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10

  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-09-23 patchlevel -1) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:

    - /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :benchmark => false
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

    - http://rubygems.org/
    - http://gems.github.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an old prerelease version of Ruby that debugger doesn't support. The actual release version of Ruby 1.9.3 has been out for some time, and upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3-p194 (which debugger supports) will allow it to install.